# Why won't Google Chrome browser let me visit https://www.torproject.org?

Tags: chrome, torproject.org

When using Google's Chrome browser to visit https://www.torproject.org I am rejected by the browser with the following message:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from
>   www.torproject.org (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).
>
> Advanced info: www.torproject.org normally uses encryption to protect
>   your information. When Chrome tried to connect to www.torproject.org
>   this time, the website sent back unusual and incorrect credentials.
>   Either an attacker is trying to pretend to be www.torproject.org, or a
>   Wi-Fi sign-in screen has interrupted the connection. Your information
>   is still secure because Chrome stpped the connection before any data
>   was exchanged.
>
> You cannot visit www.torproject right now because the website uses
>   HSTS. Network errrors and attacks are usually temporary, so this page
>   will probably work later.
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

My request is not being intercepted by a Wi-Fi sign-in.
Is this a misconfiguration of my browser? the webserver at www.torproject.org?Or is this likely an actual attack?

*Google's help documentation on this occurence is here: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/4454607

Comment: answer is: update your Chrome browser

Comment: The error exists when using Chrome _Version 38.0.2125.101 beta_ , which (at time of writing) is the most up-to-date version of Chome in the beta stream.

Comment: This problem still exists to today, and Safari and Firefox can no longer be used to go to torproject.org.

Comment: If the version of your operating system is too old, it will not automatically receive the proper certificates from the certificate authorities listed in Chrome -> Settings -> Advanced -> Manage Certificates

Answer (score 2):

Desktop XP sp2 IE and Chrome

Summary of my Error Message:

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 
www.torproject.org (for example, passwords, messages or credit cards).  
Etc as detailed above.
```

I get this message when trying to access lots of websites via both IE and Chrome. Tried all the suggested actions re: date and time to no avail. Tried running scans with both AVG and Malwarebytes, neither found any problem

**Solution.** I downloaded Mozilla Firefox and installed it, was able to access all websites via  Firefox.  Tried Chrome and IE and problem still there. Uninstalled Chrome, downloaded new version of Chrome and installed it, was able to access all websites via Chrome. Tried IE and was able to access all websites via IE.

**Conclusion:** Something, malware, virus, had corrupted or infected Chrome and by un-installing and reinstalling a different version it fixed the problem.